# Trigger jQuery handler if search field contains "pre-populated" value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search field that currently has an `.on('input')` event handler attached to it. However, in some instances the search field may be pre-populated if a value is passed through the URL (`http://127.0.0.1/search/query-is-here`). The issue here however is that the event handler will not be fired until the user edits the search field's value, meaning no search is automatically made.

I have tried initiating a `.trigger` by specifying `focus`, `click`, `change`, ... but none seem to work (and yes, I do change the event handler to `.on('input focus')` for example). What's the crack?

--

**JS File (referenced in the footer BEFORE the trigger)**

```
$('#search').on('input focus', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // various if statements and variable assignments
}
```

**Trigger**

```
// codeigniter -> http://ip.com/{segment 1}/{segment 2} -> this does get executed
<?php if($this->uri->segment(1) == "search" && $this->uri->segment(2)):?>
    <script>
        $('#search').focus();
        $('#search').trigger("focus");
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*My understanding of `$('#search').trigger("focus");` is that it should fire the event handler attached to `#search`, and execute the JS within that function.*

Answer (score 0):

You're subscribing to the event 'input focus' and triggering the event 'focus'. I think you'll want to subscribe to both events.

```
    $('#search').on('focus', myHandler);
    $('#search').on('focus input', myHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are placing e.preventDefault() on focus? The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.

Remove that e.preventDefault() from the code and try it again.

```
$('#search').on('input focus', function(e) { 
//remvoe this line>>   e.preventDefault();
// various if statements and variable assignments
```

}

Below is the jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/c8v5v788/1/

I have also place e.preventDefault() on the handler and it is preventing click event handler from firing .So first try it and the click event handler will not fire and then remove the e.preventDefault() and then try it again in the fiddle and this time event handler will fire